# How to get data in that form using SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have stored data in one table 't' in which I have all year data of user what I have . In result of query I want the total number of new users  as per year.

Example:

```
year , count
1991   360
1992   640
2000   2000

Result required:

Year, NewUsers
1991  360
1992  280 (640-360)
2000  1720
```

Comment: Year 2000, new users = 1720 is this wrong, I think it is 1360 = (2000 - 640) ?

Comment: @KhánhBùiĐức no each col value depend on its one previous or more previous col.

Comment: 1720 = 2000 - 280 and 280 is new user from previous year 1992. So formula is newusers = count of years -  new users from previous year, right ?

Answer (score 2):

You could define a variable to do this:

```
select
    `year`,
    @lastval := `count` - @lastval as newusers
from yourtable
cross join (select @lastval := 0) a
order by `year`
```

See [**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad61e6/6) in SQLFiddle.

Comment: select `year`, newusers from
(
select
    `year`,
    `count` - @lastval as newusers,
    @lastval := `count` - @lastval
from yourtable
cross join (select @lastval := 0) a
 ) t
order by `year`

Comment: @dev OK, I've fixed my query, plz check it.